# vector of char stars in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, char

If I declare a vector as such:

`vector<char *> charStarVec(4);`

and then add values to it like so:

```
charStarVec.at(0) = (char *) "one";
charStarVec.at(1) = (char *) "two";
charStarVec.at(2) = (char *) "three";
charStarVec.at(3) = (char *) "four";
```

Then no problems result. (I can print out all the vector elements just fine.)

But I get problems if I use character arrays (to get the data off the disk.)

The program crashes if I try to memcpy/strcpy/assign from a character array to a character pointer.

```
char *c = "blah";
char carr[5];
...
c[0] = carr[0];           //FAIL (crashes at runtime)
memcpy(c,carr,5);         //FAIL (crashes at runtime)
strcpy(c,carr,5);         //FAIL (crashes at runtime)
...
charStarVec.at(i) = carr; //FAIL (all 4 elements are the same as the last element.)
charStarVec.at(i) = c;
```

But how else am I supposed to get a vector of character pointers to data that is a copy of what was on the disk, which is variable sized and may not terminate in a null character, thus requiring me to manually add the null character.

I am fairly new to c/c++, in case it wasn't obvious.

Comment: "blah" is a constant string literal, you should not try to modify it.

Comment: It would be nice if you described how the program fails. It's not a compilation error right? 3 first lines with the comment //FAIL are invoking undefined behaviour, but the fourth is legal.

Comment: "Vector of char *stars*" lol.

Comment: thanks people.  I had no idea that anything checked memory for read-only access.  strdup and new char[length] ended up being useful.  Ordinarily I would have used a vector of strings, but I didn't write the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two reasonable routes.  Use the std::string class instead of char pointers, or use strdup(...) to copy the array to a newly allocated char* pointer once you've loaded and null terminated it:

```
charStarVec.at(4) = strdup(carr);
```

You'll have to free(...) each pointer when you're done, or you'll leak memory.

Answer (score 3):

What do you think this line does?

```
char *c = "blah";
```

What it actually does is create a pointer, called `c`. This pointer points to a string literal, which is a read-only array, containing the bytes "blah" plus a NUL terminator.

String literals cannot be modified, so `memcpy(c,carr,5)` is undefined behavior.

If you always use `const char*` pointers for string literals, then your compiler will prevent you doing this. Unfortunately, for 25-year-old legacy reasons, C++ allows a `char *` to point to a string literal without an explicit conversion.

To actually solve your problem:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec(4);
vec[0] = std::string(carr, 5);
```

There is then no need for `carr` to contain a NUL terminator, because of how `std::string` works. You can get a `const char*` pointer with `vec[0].c_str()`.

If you absolutely need a non-const `char*`, then use a `vector<vector<char> >` instead of a `vector<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as thought you still need to read up on some basics of C, such as dynamic memory allocation. In your example, creating a pointer (char* c) does not actually allocate any memory, you need to do that explicitly.

```
char *c;         //the variable c is defined, but its value is un-initialised
c = NULL;        //c now points to NULL
c = new char[5]; //an array of 5 char's is allocated, and c is set to point to that array

//...

c[0] = carr[0];     
memcpy(c,carr,5);   
strcpy(c,carr,5);   

//...

charStarVec.at(i) = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated any memory at c, 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/

Comment: that's true, but it's not the problem.  I'll edit it so it makes sense.

Comment: @user420667: you should not be modifying constant strings

Answer (score -2):

c potentially refers to read only memory, you shouldn't assign anything to the block of characters it points to.

Also, `strcpy(c,carr,5);` is one character too many, because of the NUL terminator.

Finally, this should have bene definitely tagged as homework!

Comment: that should? have been a comment instead